# Is There an Alternative Method to Replace These Anchor Links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, anchor, lightbox

I have developed a lightbox feature, made with CSS for the most part. Though it functions well at a glance, I've been facing some complications with the way that it opens and closes with anchor links, **the primary issue being that it adds on entries to the browser history**.

Here's an example of what I am referring to:

1. I load a page with an image with the lightbox feature applied.
2. I click on the image, and the lightbox window opens.
3. Then I close the lightbox window and it returns back to the page; however, doing this has now **added 2 additional history entries** by opening and closing the lightbox via the anchor links behavior, (which append the page's URL with `http://SITEURL.com/PAGEURL#theanchor`).

Judging from previous responders, linking to anchors seem to be the least recommended for producing this sort of functionality. If that is the case, how else could I implement this, (and would I potentially be able to avoid the use of anchors altogether)?

Here is a full snippet that presents the lightbox feature in action, as well as the anchor link behavior:

```js
$('.pic > img').click(function() {
  var srcToCopy = $(this).attr('src');
  $('body').find('.imgsrc').attr('src', srcToCopy);
  $('body').addClass('no-scroll');
});

$('#customlightbox-controls').on('click', function() {
  $('body').removeClass('no-scroll');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body.no-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.pic,
#imgsrc {
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  width: 100px
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 0;
}

.customlightbox {
  top: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: -5;
  opacity: 0;
}

.customlightbox-imgwrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.customlightbox img {
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#customlightbox-controls {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  top: -50px;
  right: -3px;
  z-index: 5;
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  opacity: .7;
}

#close-customlightbox {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#close-customlightbox:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 0px;
  width: 2px;
  left: 14px;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#close-customlightbox:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 2px;
  top: 14px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.customlightbox:target {
  z-index: 4;
  opacity: 1;
  display: inline-block;
}

.customlightbox:target img {
  opacity: 1;
}

.customlightbox:target~#customlightbox-controls {
  top: -3px;
}

.customlightbox:target~#customlightbox-controls #close-customlightbox:after {
  width: 30px;
}

.customlightbox:target~#customlightbox-controls #close-customlightbox:before {
  height: 30px;
}

.lb-animate {
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Lightbox Instance 1 -->
<div class="container">
  <a href="#view">
    <div class="pic">
      <img src="https://syedimranrocks.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/flower01low1.png">
    </div>
  </a>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Instance 2 -->
<div class="container">
  <a href="#view">
    <div class="pic">
      <img src="http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/Rose-Coral-Icon-906534.png">
    </div>
  </a>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Instance 3 -->
<div class="container">
  <a href="#view">
    <div class="pic">
      <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/136645/isolated/lists/54b1517db1906889a6971939de45d2a8-purple-sunflower-cartoon.png">
    </div>
  </a>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Prompt -->
<div class="customlightbox lb-animate" id="view">
  <div class="customlightbox-imgwrap">
    <img class="imgsrc" id="customlightbox-img" src="">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="customlightbox-controls" class="lb-animate">
  <a id="close-customlightbox" class="lb-animate" href="#!"></a>
</div>
```

Hopefully there is some sort of referable solution.

Comment: What is the problem? If I could understand well, your problem is what you called **history entries**! What is this problem and what could it cause bad?

Comment: @SaidbakR it’s because when an anchor is clicked on within the page, it adds an additional entry to the browser’s history, which I do not want.

Comment: Do you mean the image src URL?

Comment: @SaidbakR No, the page's url gets appended when I click on an anchor link, not the image's.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally posted this answer but, you can remove anchor tags and and just add cursor: pointer; css to your .pic class.

```js
$('.pic > img').click(function() {
  var srcToCopy = $(this).attr('src');
  $('body').find('.imgsrc').attr('src', srcToCopy);
  $('body').addClass('no-scroll');
});

$('#customlightbox-controls').on('click', function() {
  $('body').removeClass('no-scroll');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body.no-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.pic,
#imgsrc {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

img {
  width: 100px
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 0;
}

.customlightbox {
  top: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: -5;
  opacity: 0;
}

.customlightbox-imgwrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.customlightbox img {
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#customlightbox-controls {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  top: -50px;
  right: -3px;
  z-index: 5;
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  opacity: .7;
}

#close-customlightbox {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#close-customlightbox:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 0px;
  width: 2px;
  left: 14px;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#close-customlightbox:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 2px;
  top: 14px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.customlightbox:target {
  z-index: 4;
  opacity: 1;
  display: inline-block;
}

.customlightbox:target img {
  opacity: 1;
}

.customlightbox:target~#customlightbox-controls {
  top: -3px;
}

.customlightbox:target~#customlightbox-controls #close-customlightbox:after {
  width: 30px;
}

.customlightbox:target~#customlightbox-controls #close-customlightbox:before {
  height: 30px;
}

.lb-animate {
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Lightbox Instance 1 -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="pic">
      <img src="https://syedimranrocks.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/flower01low1.png">
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Instance 2 -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="pic">
      <img src="http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/Rose-Coral-Icon-906534.png">
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Instance 3 -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="pic">
      <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/136645/isolated/lists/54b1517db1906889a6971939de45d2a8-purple-sunflower-cartoon.png">
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Prompt -->
<div class="customlightbox lb-animate" id="view">
  <div class="customlightbox-imgwrap">
    <img class="imgsrc" id="customlightbox-img" src="">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="customlightbox-controls" class="lb-animate">
  <a id="close-customlightbox" class="lb-animate" href="#!"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, ok... But this doesn't activate the lightbox at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could just prevent the default action and not add the hash to the url (or history)

```
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function(evt){
   evt.preventDefault()
});
```

Has been a long time since I have used Lightbox and not sure if this will conflict with it's features or not

Comment: thanks for checking my post. I appreciate the suggestion, but it doesn't seem to work when I applied it to the snippet... Still stumped.